# Simulating Li-ion charge management IC

Tags: power-supply, simulation

I am designing a power supply for a system which will require a 5v line and a 3.3v line and the ability to provide these lines from mains or a backup lithium-ion battery pack. The power supply must be able to charge the lithium-ion battery while mains power is connected and be able to automatically switch over to battery power when mains is disconnected. From 230v ac wall power I will use a full-bridge rectifier to obtain 12v dc. I would then like to use this 12v as input to the following circuit based around the TI BQ24103 charge management IC to do the charging of a two cell lithium-ion battery. Switch over is controlled with MOSFETS Q1, Q2 and Q3.

When VIN is on, the input powers the system directly via Q1 and Q2 and the charger at the same time.
Q3 is off during this time. When the input adapter is removed, Q1 and Q2 turn off and Q3 turns on. This
action ties the battery to the system.
Soft turnon of Q2 may be necessary to minimize the inrush current during the transition. The turnon time
of Q2 can be adjusted by changing the value of the capacitor C1 across the gate and source.

[image: charging and switch over]

From the source of MOSFET Q3 my plan is to connect two buck converter circuits (one to get the 5v output and one for the 3.3v output). The buck converter circuits will need to provide their 5v or 3.3v output from either the 12v Vin or the 7.4v from the battery back depending on whether the mains power is on or off.

I would like to simulate this circuit either in LTspice or Orcad to test if it will work but I am uncertain how to go about this, I unfortunately can't find any spice models for the BQ24103. How would I approach simulation of this circuit?

Comment: You can try to roll your own model by looking at the datasheet. Most of the functions could be implemented behaviourally, to simplify things (and speed up the simulation), and LTspice also knows state machine. I can only wish you good luck at this point. :-)

Comment: I'm not particularly experienced with simulation software so I suspect that modelling this IC will be well beyond my ability. Would it be safe to assume that if the circuit comes from the application section of the datasheet it should work?

Comment: Yes, that part of the datasheet deals with providing a (usually) low complexity circuit that is *guaranteed* to work. Of course, it's not fixed, improvements can be made/added/changed/etc, but, as it is, it should work.